# Implementing my own RoleProvider-and-MembershipProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, membership-provider, asp.net-roles

Hello and thanks in advance

I'm lost and i don't know whats wrong with my code, and i've been trying to follow a tutorial found at 
http://www.brianlegg.com/post/2011/05/09/Implementing-your-own-RoleProvider-and-MembershipProvider-in-MVC-3.aspx   and making changes to match my own DB.

firstly here is the relevant part of my DB script (ssms)

```
CREATE TABLE BFS.dbo.BFSSUSER(

ID              int IDENTITY(1,1),
RoleID          int,
Name            nvarchar(50)NOT NULL,
SiteName        nvarchar(50)NOT NULL,
UserPassword    nvarchar(20),

CONSTRAINT BFSSUSER_pk PRIMARY KEY (ID))


GO
USE BFS
GO

CREATE TABLE BFS.dbo.ROLE(
ID          int IDENTITY(1,1),
Name            nvarchar(50)NOT NULL


CONSTRAINT ROLE_pk PRIMARY KEY (ID),
CONSTRAINT ROLE_fk FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES BFSUSER(ID)) 

GO
```

okay now Im trying to make my providers and using a repository class

I will include my entire code on it but ill identify from where my errors start
and i don't know what to do

(all the if roleExists statements in mine are red and driving me nuts (34 errors!!!), I have tried several combinations to get them to go away and (well i suck basically)  any and all help would be greatly appreciated  (bare in mind i m brand spanking new to asp.net and have no idea what anything is or means!!)

here's my code

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;

    namespace BFS.Models
    {
        public class BFSRepository
        {
             private BFSEntities entities = new BFSEntities();

        private const string MissingRole = "Role does not exist";
        private const string MissingUser = "User does not exist";
        private const string TooManyUser = "User already exists";
        private const string TooManyRole = "Role already exists";
        private const string AssignedRole = "Cannot delete a role with assigned users";



        #region Properties

        public int NumberOfUsers
        {
            get
            {
                return this.entities.BFSUSERs.Count();
            }
        }

        public int NumberOfRoles
        {
            get
            {
                return this.entities.ROLEs.Count();
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Constructors

        public BFSRepository()
        {
            this.entities = new BFSEntities();
        }

        #endregion

        #region Query Methods

        public IQueryable<BFSUSER> GetAllUsers()
        {
            return from user in entities.BFSUSERs
                   orderby user.ID
                   select user;
        }

         public BFSUSER GetUser(int id)
        {
            return entities.BFSUSERs.SingleOrDefault(user => user.ID == id);
        }

        public BFSUSER GetUser(string userName)
        {
            return entities.BFSUSERs.SingleOrDefault(user => user.SiteName == userName);
        }

     FROM HERE ON DOWN IS WHERE ALL MY ERRORS START
     "entities does not contain a definition for 'Roles' etc etc missing assem ref

        public IQueryable<BFSUSER> GetUsersForRole(string Name)
        {
            return GetUsersForRole(ROLE(Name));
        }

        public IQueryable<BFSUSER> GetUsersForRole(int id)
        {
            return GetUsersForRole(GetRole(id));
        }

        public IQueryable<ROLE> GetUsersForRole(Roles role)
        {
            if (!ExistsROLE(role))
                throw new ArgumentException(MissingRole);

            return from user in entities.BFSUSERs
                   where user.RoleID == role.ID
                   orderby user.SiteName
                   select user;
        }

        public IQueryable<ROLE> GetAllRoles()
        {
            return from role in entities.ROLEs
                   orderby role.Name
                   select role;
        }

        public ROLE GetRole(int id)
        {
            return entities.ROLEs.SingleOrDefault(role => role.ID == id);
        }

        public ROLE GetRole(string name)
        {
            return entities.ROLEs.SingleOrDefault(role => role.Name == name);
        }

        public ROLE GetRoleForUser(string SiteName)
        {
            return GetRoleForUser(GetUser(SiteName));
        }

        public ROLE GetRoleForUser(int id)
        {
            return GetRoleForUser(GetUser(id));
        }

        public ROLE GetRoleForUser(User user)
        {
            if (!UserExists(user))
                throw new ArgumentException(MissingUser);

            return user.Role;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Insert/Delete

        private void AddUser(BFSUSER user)
        {
            if (BFSUSERExists(user))
                throw new ArgumentException(TooManyUser);

            entities.BFSUSERs.Add(user);
        }

        public void CreateUser(string name, string SiteName, string UserPassword, string roleName)
        {
            ROLE role = GetRole(roleName);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SiteName.Trim()))
                throw new ArgumentException("The user name provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again.");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name.Trim()))
                throw new ArgumentException("The name provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again.");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserPassword.Trim()))
                throw new ArgumentException("The password provided is invalid. Please enter a valid password value.");
            if (!roleExists(role))
                throw new ArgumentException("The role selected for this user does not exist! Contact an administrator!");
            if (this.entities.BFSUSERs.Any(user => user.SiteName == SiteName))
                throw new ArgumentException("Username already exists. Please enter a different user name.");

            newUser = new User()
           {
               UserName = SiteName,
               Name = name,
               Password = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(UserPassword.Trim(), "md5"),
               RoleID = role.ID
           };

            try
            {
                AddUser(newUser);
            }
            catch (ArgumentException ae)
            {
                throw ae;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("The authentication provider returned an error. Please verify your entry and try again. " +
                    "If the problem persists, please contact your system administrator.");
            }

            // Immediately persist the user data
            Save();
        }

        public void DeleteUser( user)
        {
            if (!UserExists(user))
                throw new ArgumentException(MissingUser);

            entities.BFSUSERs.DeleteObject(user);
        }

        public void DeleteUser(string userName)
        {
            DeleteUser(GetUser(userName));
        }

        public void AddRole(Roles role)
        {
            if (RolesExists(role))
                throw new ArgumentException(TooManyRole);

            entities.Roles.AddObject(role);
        }

        public void AddRole(string roleName)
        {
            Role role = new Role()
            {
                Name = roleName
            };

            AddRole(role);
        }

        public void DeleteRole(Role role)
        {
            if (!RoleExists(role))
                throw new ArgumentException(MissingRole);

            if (GetUsersForRole(role).Count() > 0)
                throw new ArgumentException(AssignedRole);

            entities.Roles.DeleteObject(role);
        }

        public void DeleteRole(string roleName)
        {
            DeleteRole(GetRole(roleName));
        }

        #endregion

        #region Persistence

        public void Save()
        {
            entities.SaveChanges();
        }

        #endregion

        #region Helper Methods

        public bool UserExists(User user)
        {
            if (user == null)
                return false;

            return (entities.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.ID == user.ID || u.UserName == user.UserName) != null);
        }

        public bool RoleExists(Roles role)
        {
            if (role == null)
                return false;

            return (entities.BFSUSERs.SingleOrDefault(r => r.ID == role.ID || r.Name == role.Name) != null);
        }

        #endregion

    }


}
```

ANY AND ALL HELP would be greatly appreciated

especially explaining or showing to me when it needs to be the Table Name, variable Name etc. I'm confused as my Table name is Role and what I'm doing is role

Comment: DONT WORRY about making any DB amendments, its all good, im just concentrating on the asp.net code

Answer (score 1):

Creating an custom membership provider in a few steps:

1. create a class which inherits from MembershipProvider (MVC3) or ExtendedMembershipProvider(MVC4)
2. let Visual Studio implement all required members,  now you have a class with a lot of members which have a `throw new NotImplementedException();` body
3. now the difficult thing: identify the methods you actually have to override. For basic functionality you will need:

   - `public override MembershipUser GetUser(object providerUserKey, bool userIsOnline)`
   - `public override MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline)`
   - `public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)`
4. Fill the body of the methods above, with the necessary code for your user management
5. Configure the web.config for using your custom membership provider:

   ```
   <membership defaultProvider="CurrentProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="10">
     <providers>
       <add name="CurrentProvider" Type="YOUR.WEBAPP.PROVIDERS.CustomMembershipProvider" />
     </providers>
   </membership>
   ```

   for MVC4 must add or set the following AppSettings:

   ```
   <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false" />
   <add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
   ```

For a custom role provider it's nearly the same procedure

1. see above except: use `RoleProvider` (MVC3 and 4) for inheritance
2. see above
3. see above, except: the needed methods are :

   - `public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)`
   - `public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)`
4. see above
5. ```
   <roleManager defaultProvider="CurrentProvider" enabled="true">
     <providers>
       <add name="CurrentProvider" type="YOUR.WEBAPP.PROVIDERS.CustomRoleProvider" />
     </providers>
   </roleManager>
   ```

If when you use membership functions and an NotImplementedException is throw you know you have to override the method where the exception is thrown.